# QToolButton with popup QSlider

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qslider, qtoolbutton

I'm trying to make volume button, on click it should mute/unmute and and on hover it should popup `QSlider`, so user can set whatever level he wants. Now I'm trying to achieve this by showing slider window in `enterEvent` and hiding it in `leaveEvent`:

```
class VolumeButton(QToolButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setIcon(volumeicon)

        self.slider = QSlider()
        self.slider.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.slider.setWindowModality(Qt.NonModal)

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.slider.move(self.mapToGlobal(self.rect().topLeft()))
        self.slider.show()

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.slider.hide()
```

The problem is that `mapToGlobal` seems to be connected in some way with `enterEvent` and it creates recursion, but without `mapToGlobal` I can't place slider at the right position.
I'm not sure that `QToolButton` and `FramelessWindow` are the right widgets to achieve wished result, so let me know if there a better ways to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not from `mapToGlobal`, but from the fact that the `leaveEvent` is fired as soon as the slider is shown: since the slider is in the same coordinates of the mouse, Qt considers that the mouse has "left" the button (and "entered" the slider).

You cannot use the simple leaveEvent for this, as you need to check the cursor position against both the button *and* the slider.

A possible solution is to create a QRegion that contains the geometry of both widgets and check if the cursor is inside it. In order to process the mouse events of the slider, an event filter must be installed on it:

```
class VolumeButton(QToolButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setIcon(volumeicon)

        self.slider = QSlider()
        self.slider.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.slider.setWindowModality(Qt.NonModal)
        self.slider.installEventFilter(self)

    def isInside(self):
        buttonRect = self.rect().translated(self.mapToGlobal(QPoint()))
        if not self.slider.isVisible():
            return QCursor.pos() in buttonRect
        region = QRegion(buttonRect)
        region |= QRegion(self.slider.geometry())
        return region.contains(QCursor.pos())

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        if not self.slider.isVisible():
            self.slider.move(self.mapToGlobal(QPoint()))
            self.slider.show()

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        if not self.isInside():
            self.slider.hide()

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if source == self.slider and event.type() == event.Leave:
            if not self.isInside():
                self.slider.hide()
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)
```

Note that `self.rect()` is always at coordinates `(0, 0)`, so you can just use `self.mapToGlobal(QPoint())` to get the widget's global position. On the other hand, you might want to show the slider "outside" the button, so you could use `self.mapToGlobal(self.rect().bottomLeft())`.
Be aware that trying to place the slider "outside" the button geometry might result in a problem if the user moves the mouse in the gap between the button and the slider; in that case, you will need to create a valid region that covers both widgets **and** a reasonable space between them.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for!
In addition wanted to ask, that's not related to answer, if I don't give parent to `self.slider`, how can I  
1) be sure that it will be deleted when `VolumeButton` will be deleted  
2) where it will be proper place to call `removeEventFilter`, coz without it, program throws SegFault at `if source == self.slider`, coz self doesn't exist anymore

Comment: If you want the slider as a standalone window while keeping parenthood, you have to *add* the window flag: `self.slider.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Window)`; this should also solve the second question, as the event filter (the button) would be deleted before that.

Comment: nice, two problems in one hit! thanks a lot for contributing to my knowledge!